# How to update recyclerview adapter from service

Tags: android

I just wanted to know is there any way to invoke method of Recyclerview.Adapter class from Service class, that is notifiDataSetChanged.

That reason to do that is when service updates the global audio id, it will match the item in recylerview and change its background color, but it doesnt update without scrolling, but its should do when i invoke notifydatasetchanged method.

So is there any solution, I tried number of ways and they are the following:

1. I created empty recyclerview constructor, and tried to invoke notifydatasetchanged method, But it did'nt worked.

and more 2 solutions tried but failed which are similar as above.

I wanted to know that is it possible from the fragment that is having recyclerview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Comment: But is it possible to receive it in Recyclerview.Adapter ???

Comment: @HussainID you can listen broadcast in activity/fragment which holds adapter object and then notify your adapter.

Comment: Ok I fixed it! Thanks @ ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: Yes you can receive it in  class  in which extending `Adapter`

Comment: just use `"bound service"` pattern, most likely `"bound local service"`, more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)